# JQuery Date picker Range

Tags: jquery

Help Guys! I want to display in my textarea the month and year of my dateFrom after selecting the date. I have no problem on datepicker1.

I want to display on my date_month (May 2021) not the start and end date

here is my code

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker1" class="form-control">
<input type="text" id="date_month" class="form-control">

<script type="text/javascript">
        function log (message) {    
            document.querySelector('#date_month').value = message
        }

        window.onload = function () {
            document.querySelector('#datepicker1').addEventListener('datechanged', function(e) {
                console.log('New date', e.data, this.value)
            })

            duDatepicker('#datepicker1', {
                format: 'mmmm d, yyyy', range: true, clearBtn: true,
                // disabledDays: ['Sat', 'Sun'],
                events: {
                    dateChanged: function (data) {
                        log('From: ' + data.dateFrom + '\nTo: ' + data.dateTo)
                    },
                    onRangeFormat: function (from, to) {
                        var fromFormat = 'mmmm d, yyyy', toFormat = 'mmmm d, yyyy';

                        if (from.getMonth() === to.getMonth() && from.getFullYear() === to.getFullYear()) {
                            fromFormat = 'mmmm d'
                            toFormat = 'd, yyyy'
                        } else if (from.getFullYear() === to.getFullYear()) {
                            fromFormat = 'mmmm d'
                            toFormat = 'mmmm d, yyyy'
                        }

                        return from.getTime() === to.getTime() ?
                            this.formatDate(from, 'mmmm d, yyyy') :
                            [this.formatDate(from, fromFormat), this.formatDate(to, toFormat)].join('-');
                    }
                }
            })`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `dateChanged` function: format the `dateFrom` and call `log`.

```js
function log(message) {
  document.querySelector('#date_month').value = message
}

window.onload = function() {
  document.querySelector('#datepicker1').addEventListener('datechanged', function(e) {
    console.log('New date', e.data, this.value)
  })

  duDatepicker('#datepicker1', {
    format: 'mmmm d, yyyy',
    range: true,
    clearBtn: true,
    // disabledDays: ['Sat', 'Sun'],
    events: {
      dateChanged: function(data) {
        log(this.formatDate(data.dateFrom, 'mmm yyyy'));
      },
      onRangeFormat: function(from, to) {
        var fromFormat = 'mmmm d, yyyy',
          toFormat = 'mmmm d, yyyy';

        if (from.getMonth() === to.getMonth() && from.getFullYear() === to.getFullYear()) {
          fromFormat = 'mmmm d'
          toFormat = 'd, yyyy'
        } else if (from.getFullYear() === to.getFullYear()) {
          fromFormat = 'mmmm d'
          toFormat = 'mmmm d, yyyy'
        }

        return from.getTime() === to.getTime() ?
          this.formatDate(from, 'mmmm d, yyyy') : [this.formatDate(from, fromFormat), this.formatDate(to, toFormat)].join('-');
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="datepicker1" class="form-control">
<input type="text" id="date_month" class="form-control">


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/dmuy/duDatepicker@2.0.1-rc/dist/duDatepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/dmuy/duDatepicker@2.0.1-rc/dist/duDatepicker.min.css">
```

Annotation: In your question is not clear which format you want. First you said "mm-yyyy", then "May 2021". I've used the latter. Changing this should be trivial.